# Pass a config file to Sagemaker training program

Tags: python, amazon-sagemaker

Setup:

I have gone for the bring your own container option for AWS Sagemaker Training. In the Dockerfile, I specify the `SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM` variable to point to `tools/train.py` as I am working with mmaction2 repo.

So a user is executing

```
estimator = PyTorch(
    role='sagemaker_role',
    image_uri="path_in_ecr",
    instance_count=1,
    instance_type="ml.g4dn.xlarge",
    volume_size=40,
    output_path=f"s3://{bucket}/{prefix_output}/",
    sagemaker_session=sagemaker_session,
    max_run=3600 * 2,
)

estimator.fit()
```

on an ec2 machine where say they have a config in `/home/ubuntu/train_config_mmaction2.py`

Problem:
Since mmaction2 requires a config file as input which specifies the training config, how can I pass a file to Sagemaker Training so that it is copied from the calling ec2 instance to the training instance and used as a command line argument for the `SAGEMAKER_PROGRAM` defined in the Dockerfile?

I tried using the `entrypoint` and `source_code` argument provided in the pytorch class where the entrypoint and the config is in the source_code directory so that the config would be copied. However, this creates a dependency on have the entrypoint present locally for each run.
I am wondering if there is a way to do this without having this dependency

Comment: using entrypoint is the better approach. Another way i can think of is to pass the config as a input channel to the fit method. For this the config should be uploaded to s3 and the path should be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you can do multiple things:

1. Either have the config file in the `source_dir`, along with the entry point. This doesn't have to be local, it can also come from a git repo, as indicated here: [blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/git-integration-now-available-for-amazon-sagemaker-python-sdk/), [demo](https://github.com/aws/amazon-sagemaker-examples/blob/main/sagemaker-python-sdk/pytorch_lstm_word_language_model/pytorch_rnn.ipynb)
2. Or you could bring the config file via S3, using SageMaker input or checkpoint channels ([doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/model-train-storage.html))

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the response. Option 2 is preferable.
I know that I can send command line arguments. Can I read the file bytes, convert them to a string and send that as an argument?